# Copy-paste from keepass2 to Midori or WebKitGTK in general, on Linux

Tags: linux, keepass, mono-framework

Running **keepass 2.18**, which is **Mono**-based, on Xubuntu 12.04, 
I can't seem to copy-paste usernames or passwords from **keepass2** to Midori.

I can copy from keepass2 then paste into other applications such as Firefox, leafpad, xterm.
And paste to Midori from other apps than keepass2.

I think the problem does not occur with *Midori* only, but with other programs relying on *WebKitGTK*.

Do you have ideas ?

Comment: can I expand the question to copy-pasting in general on linux? Because it doesn't work in the console too (this isn't be webkitGTK, right?) which is veeery annoying

Comment: I don't know. What do you mean by console ? I can do ctrl-B or ctrl-C in keepass2 then ctrl-shift-V in xfce-terminal.

Comment: console, terminal, command line - potato/potato ;)

Comment: This answer solved a very similar problem for me: xdotool and xsel were missing on my machine. source: http://superuser.com/a/939216/286021